# Bulk posts from DRAFT Section

Tags: posts, bulk

So, i did create a website with 110k posts and i need to test some SEO features, so i did clone the same database and i did post them on 5 other domains.
The thing is i can't index them 110k posts at a single time by google cus it isn't gonna go up, so i need a code to posts like 5000 - 10000 posts per day onto a random time postbased.

I've tried this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/drafts-scheduler/ But it only allows 999 posts per day to be scheduled, i did try to modify the number of allowed characters on the php code but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An way to do that is using SQL. You probably have access to the database, so you can run this daily. It's not automatic, but will solve your problem

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status='publish' WHERE post_status='draft' AND post_type='post' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5000
```

Just to explain what this line do: It will get 5000 items (LIMIT 5000) in a random order (ORDER BY rand()) and will transform the status to published (post_status='publish') on every record that is a post (post_type='post') and the status is draft (post_status='draft').

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Works quite well! Thanks you André, theres a way to publish them randomly through the day? And also, there's a way the date added changes to the same time it is being published? Let me explain myself, i started the principal website on march 2016 and so a lot of posts still have this date in the database, so i need to change them automatically to the same time this SQL Query is working, Thanks buddy!

Comment: @AlejandroMartín It's already random. About the date, you can do that by adding ", post_date=NOW(), post_date_gmt=NOW(), post_modified=NOW(), post_modified_gmt=NOW()" after  post_status='publish'. The problem here is that you should consider the timezone in those _gmt fields, but since I'm not an expert in SQL I can't tell you how to do it. :(

If you this helps, don't forget to choose as an answer ;)

Comment: Im trying with this code  UPDATE wpls_posts SET post_status='publish' post_date=NOW(+1) post_date_gmt=NOW(+1) post_modified=NOW(+1) post_modified_gmt=NOW(+1) WHERE post_status='draft' AND post_type='post' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1 but doesn't seem to work, what i am missing here? Thanks André

Comment: @AlejandroMartín You've missed the commas :) `UPDATE wpls_posts SET post_status='publish', post_date=NOW(), post_date_gmt=NOW(), post_modified=NOW(), post_modified_gmt=NOW() WHERE post_status='draft' AND post_type='post' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1` Also, the +1 inside NOW() doesn't take any effect. NOW doesn't accept parameters

Comment: Thanks André, it is working perfectly now, how i can rate your question as the best answer?

Comment: @AlejandroMartín honestly I don't know. I've never asked questions here :p I found this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235